# the path to the sheet is correct, but the bar chart is not getting added to the sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlsx

I am trying to add the bar chart to the excel sheet , but eventually it is not getting added to the sheet.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart,Reference
path = "C:\\Users\\nEW u\\Desktop\\new.xlsx"
newob = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
sheetob = newob.active
rows = [
    ('Number', 'Batch 1', 'Batch 2'),
    (2, 10, 30),
    (3, 40, 60),
    (4, 50, 70),
    (5, 20, 10),
    (6, 10, 40),
    (7, 50, 30),
]


for row in rows:
    sheetob.append(row)
values = Reference(sheetob, min_col = 2, min_row = 1, max_col = 7, max_row = 3)
values1 =  Reference(sheetob, min_col =1, min_row = 2, max_row = 7)
chart = BarChart()
chart.add_data(values)
chart.title = 'Bar Chart'
chart.x_axis.title = 'X-axis'
chart.y_axis.title = 'Y-axis'
sheetob.add_chart(chart, "I3")
newob.save("new.xlsx")
```

NO error message is shown.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to save the plot as png first and then export to a workbook, the below code will export to the input excel at the A1 cell and resave as output excel

````
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('input.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

img = openpyxl.drawing.image.Image('myplot.png')
ws.add_image(ws.cell('A1'))

ws.save('output.xlsx')```
````